# How to write custom rules for ktlint in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lint

I have been trying to write custom rules for ktlint. When I try to execute my custom rule via terminal I get no errors, standard rules of ktlint are executed but my custom rules are ignored. May be somebody has any ideas what I am missing?

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'java-library'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.40'
id 'maven'
}

group 'com.xxx'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    ktlint
}


dependencies {
    compileOnly "com.pinterest.ktlint:ktlint-core:0.32.0"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.10.0"
    testCompile "com.pinterest.ktlint:ktlint-core:0.32.0"
    testCompile "com.pinterest.ktlint:ktlint-test:0.32.0"
}

task ktlint(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
    main = 'com.pinterest.ktlint.Main'
    // adding compiled classes to the classpath so that ktlint would validate project's sources
    // using its own ruleset (in other words to dogfood)
    classpath = configurations.ktlint + sourceSets.main.output
    args '--debug', 'src/**/*.kt'
}

check.dependsOn ktlint
```

My custom rule class (for testing purposes it is supposed to emit always an lint error):

```
package com.xxx.ktlint

import com.pinterest.ktlint.core.Rule
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.lang.ASTNode

class TempRule : Rule("no-var") {

    override fun visit(
        node: ASTNode,
        autoCorrect: Boolean,
        emit: (offset: Int, errorMessage: String, canBeAutoCorrected: Boolean) -> Unit
    ) {
        emit(node.startOffset, "#### TEST: KTLINT ERROR", false)
    }
}
```

My `com.pinterest.ktlint.core.RuleSetProvider`:

```
com.xxx.ktlint.CustomRuleSetProvider
```

I create the jar by executing the gradle task "jar" and then I execute ktlint like this in the terminal:

```
ktlint -R ../path/to/ktlint-rules.jar "path/to/file/**/file-to-be-checked.kt"
```

I get no errors and ktlint applies to the file that should be checked all the standard rules as expected but my custom rules are just ignored. The jar-file itself does not seem to be ignored since when I put a non existing name in the command I get an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try running `ktlint --verbose -R ../path/to/ktlint-rules.jar "path/to/file/**/file-to-be-checked.kt"`. It should show you custom rule being loaded. If it doesn't - make sure `../path/to/ktlint-rules.jar` contains `META-INF/services/com.pinterest.ktlint.core.RuleSetProvider` (check the path).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried adding `--verbose`. The output doesn't change. It is still the same: `ktlint --verbose -R ../ktlint-rules/build/libs/ktlint-rules.jar "path/to/file/**/file-to-be-checked.kt"
path/to/file/xxx/file-to-be-checked.kt:4:1: Wildcard import (cannot be auto-corrected) (no-wildcard-imports)` (applying the standard rules but not the custom rule)
I checked the ktlint-rules.jar and it does contain exactly `META-INF/services/com.pinterest.ktlint.core.RuleSetProvider`

Comment: I've always just ran the gradle task "jar". That works fine. If I run the gradle task "build", I get the error `Task :ktlint FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class com.pinterest.ktlint.Main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had installed locally ktlint with Version `0.31.0` (before pinterest took over the code) and in my `build.gradle` I was using `0.33.0` (after ptinerest took over the code). Since many packages got renamed those different version wouldn't get along with each other. After updating my local ktlint to version `0.33.0` the custom rule was applied as expected.

Comment: How to apply the custom rules to multi module project?